# A sum of modular inverses of one prime for different moduli

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

**Note:** Here, for given $m$ and $a$, I define $a^{-1}_m \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, m-1\} $, such that $a \cdot a^{-1}_m \equiv 1 \pmod  m $.

---

Say, we have a prime $p$ and a whole positive number $n$ ($n < p$). I want to sum up the following (that is, write down some $S(n, p)$ which would return such a sum for given numbers):

$$
p^{-1}_2 + p^{-1}_3 + \dots + p^{-1}_n
$$

For example:

$$
S(3, 5) = 5^{-1}_2 + 5^{-1}_3 = 1 + 2 = 3
$$

My only idea so far is multiplying this row by $p$. We know that:

$$
p \cdot p^{-1}_m \equiv 1 \pmod m \\
p \cdot p^{-1}_m = 1+ Q \cdot m
$$

Therefore:

$$
p\Big(p^{-1}_2 + p^{-1}_3 + \dots + p^{-1}_n\Big) = \\ = (1 + Q_2 \cdot 2) + (1 + Q_3 \cdot 3) + \dots + (1 + Q_n \cdot n) = \\
= n + 2 \cdot Q_2 + 3 \cdot Q_3 + \dots + n \cdot Q_n
$$

Yet, I see no way to go about those $Q$s.

Am I thinking in the right way at least? How could this be done? I would like a hint instead of a full solution :).

---

[metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy) asked to say a bit where this is coming from. Just to be clear: this question is **NOT** from an online-olympiad. Yet, there is a problem form an olympiad which I tired solving with inverses. As this my first time meeting the inverses in the field, I wanted to fetch some ideas from here (might have been a bit unfair - I agree; sorry).

Here is the problem:

> **Original:** Главная достопримечательность города N—небоскрёб с бесконечным количеством этажей, пронумерованных целыми положительными числами (1, 2, 3, . . .).
> Основный метод передвижения внутри небоскрёба—лифт с $n + 1$ кнопкой: $i$-я из
> них при $1 \le i \le n$ — это кнопка «подняться на $i$ этажей вверх», а $(n + 1)$-я—«опу-
> ститься вниз на p этажей», где $p$ — простое число, большее $n$. Если номер этажа, на
> котором вы находитесь, не превосходит $p$, то нажатие на последнюю кнопку ничего
> не делает.
> Вы слышали от знакомого математика, что для того, чтобы попасть с любого
> этажа на любой другой, достаточно двух кнопок: любой из первых $n$ и последней.
> Вы решили проверить это утверждение на практике следующим образом: сперва
> попасть с первого этажа на второй, нажимая только на первую и последнюю кнопки,
> потом со второго на третий, нажимая только на вторую и последнюю кнопки, . . .,
> наконец, попасть с $n$-го этажа на $(n + 1)$-й, нажимая только на n-ю и последнюю
> кнопки.
> Несмотря на частое использование, последняя кнопка всё ещё работает прекрас-
> но, а вот первые $n$ иногда плохо нажимаются. Поэтому вы решили минимизировать
> суммарное количество нажатий на первые n кнопок в процессе эксперимента. Чему
> равно искомое минимальное количество нажатий?
> Можно доказать, что для каждого $i$ от $1$ до $n$ с любого этажа можно попасть на
> любой другой, используя только кнопки с номерами $i$ и $n + 1$.

> **My translation:** The main landmark of the city N is the skyscraper with an infinite amount of floors, enumerated with whole positives. The main way to get around the skyscraper is an elevator with $n + 1$ buttons. For $1 \le i \le n$: i<sup>th</sup> buttons takes one up $i$ floors. The $(n + 1)$<sup>st</sup> button takes one down $p$ floors, where $p$ is some given prime (it works only if you are on the $p$<sup>th</sup> floor or higher.) Your fellow mathematician reckons one to be able to get on any floor from any floor using 2 buttons only: the last one and some other. You decided to check this statement with an experiment: you want to get from the 1<sup>st</sup> floor to the 2<sup>nd</sup> using the 1<sup>st</sup> and the last buttons, from the 2<sup>nd</sup> to the 3<sup>rd</sup> using the 2<sup>nd</sup> and the last buttons, and so on up to the $(n + 1)$<sup>st</sup> floor (with the last and the $n$<sup>th</sup> buttons). Despite being used quite often, the last button works just fine, unlike others. Therefore, you want to push all buttons but the last one the least possible amount of times. Output it for given $n$ and $p$. One can prove that it is indeed possible to get around the skyscraper using the last button and some other button only.

**Spoiler:** here is a row I reckon to be the right answer to the problem:

> $1 + {1 + p \cdot p^{-1}_2 \over 2} + {1 + p \cdot p^{-1}_3 \over 3} + \dots + {1 + p \cdot p^{-1}_n \over n}$

Alas, I didn't manage to calculate it fast enough in a cycle.

The olympiad itself: [Олимпиада СПбГУ по информатике среди школьников](https://olympiada.spbu.ru/informatika/).
Заочный тур, сезон 2020-2021, Задача I.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118286/discussion-on-question-by-zhiltsoff-igor-a-sum-of-modulo-inverts-of-one-prime-fo).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  If $p,q$ are two primes $>n$ then I claim that $p\equiv q\pmod {n!}\implies S(n,p)=S(n,q)$.  That's what my argument is intended to prove.  For example, you showed $S(3,5)=3$.  Since $3!=6$ we could try $q=11$.  Note that the inverses are the same, so we again have $S(3,11)=3$.

Comment: If this is an online programming challenge, it is customary here to provide a link to the source. (And if it's still ongoing, asking such a question is not fair.)

Comment: @metamorphy this problem is not from an online challenge. Although it is inspired by a problem from an olympiad (which was ongoing for the last 3 month and is ending tomorrow). The statement has nothing to do with inverses. Truth be told, it's the first time I meet inverses *in the field*, therefore I lack ideas as to how they are used (hence, the question). If you are interested, I can translate the problem into English and link the Russian original. Worry not: I have not spoiled it as the sum in the problem is very different (at least the one I've found) :).

Comment: Думаю, ссылка на "русский оригинал" и без перевода не повредит ;)

Comment: @metamorphy можно тогда спросить: вопрос про олимпиадную задачку возник, т. к. просто похоже, или прямо узналась какая-то именно?)) Я вообще говорил про олимпиаду СПбГУ. Просто там я ничего такого простого не нашёл (а очень хотелось) - у меня дроби какие-то полезли. Послезавтра (когда окончательно закроют уже) можем обсудить здесь или в чате, если у Вас есть решение быстрее, чем у меня (ну, и если мы действительно об одном и том же говорим).

Comment: @metamorphy Is my last edit OK?